# Как объединить строки в SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Как задавая запрос в базу данный, соединить две строчки в одну, т.е.:

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO portfolios (name, amount, taked_books)
VALUES(:whotaked, :amount, :name + ' ' + :author)", 
name=name,author=author,amount=amount,whotaked=who_taked)
```

Сделать так чтобы переменный name и author объединились?

P.S.
Если сделать вот так:

```
:name + ' ' + :author
```

То в базу данных заносится значение 0.0

Comment: о каком языке программирования идеи речь? Добавьте метку ЯП в вопрос

Comment: А если так:
concat(:name, ' ', :author)
?

Comment: Т.е. вот так написать религия не позволяет `db.execute("INSERT INTO portfolios (name, amount, taked_books)
VALUES(:whotaked, :amount, :taked_books)", 
taked_books=name + ' ' + author, amount=amount, whotaked=who_taked)`